# sql: count in a select with percentages

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to query to return like in the picture, it pretty much explains what i need.:
[image: Database result]

I have my stored proc that returns but just basic:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_TargetStatus]
AS
BEGIN
       --NOT SURE IF NEEDED
    Declare @OnTime float
    Declare @Overdue float
    Declare @AllON float
    Declare @AllOV float
    Declare @AnswON float
    Declare @AnswOV float
       --END NOT SURE IF NEEDED

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF OBJECT_ID('#tmp1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp1


    CREATE TABLE #tmp1 
    (
        AUD_ID BIGINT,
        RowCounter BIGINT,
        DistinctCounter BIGINT,
        NACounter BIGINT,
        Total BIGINT,
        [Status] VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    INSERT INTO #tmp1 EXEC [p_GetCompleteIncompleteNaOverviewSCORE] 
    --NOT SURE IF NEEDED
    Set @OnTime = (Select Count([Status])
    From #tmp1
    Where [Status] = 'OPEN')

    Set @AllON = (SELECT COUNT([Status])
    From #tmp1)

    SET @AnswON  = @OnTime/@AnswON

    Set @Overdue = (Select Count([Status])
    From #tmp1
    Where [Status] = 'CLOSED')

    Set @AllOV = (SELECT COUNT([Status])
    From #tmp1)

    SET @AnswOV  = @Overdue/@AllOV
       --END NOT SURE IF NEEDED

    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count],[Target Status] AS TargetStatus
    FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,t2.AUD_TargetDate), 101)) < CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,0,GETDATE()), 101))
            THEN 'Over Due' 
            ELSE 'On Time' END AS [Target Status]
            FROM #tmp1 t1 INNER JOIN dbo.Audit t2
            ON t1.AUD_ID = t2.AUD_ID
            WHERE t1.[Status] = 'Open') DER
    GROUP BY [Target Status]

END 
GO
```

I have tried but failed a bit. The concatination I can figure out but the percentage seems wierd to me?

Comment: Picture is not Visible. Please upload it adain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm interrested by the open expression cause for me you need one in a case and one for the other line

i did nearly the same way, like this it's a full example

```
create table #events (reqdate int, Opened tinyint)

insert into #events values (5,1)
insert into #events values (6,0)
insert into #events values (3,1)
insert into #events values (2,0)
insert into #events values (5,1)

select 'Closed : ' + RTRIM(SUM(case when Opened = 0 then 1 else 0 end)) + ' out of ' + rtrim(count(*)),
cast(SUM(case when Opened = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as float) / COUNT(*)
from #events
union
select 'Open : ' + RTRIM(SUM(case when Opened = 1 then 1 else 0 end)) + ' out of ' + rtrim(count(*)),
cast(SUM(case when Opened = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as float) / COUNT(*)
from #events

drop table #events
```

here is copy of the method from below without union

```
create table #events (reqdate int, Opened tinyint)

insert into #events values (5,1)
insert into #events values (6,0)
insert into #events values (3,1)
insert into #events values (2,0)
insert into #events values (5,1)

select 'Closed : ' + RTRIM(SUM(case when Opened = blabla then 1 else 0 end)) + ' out of ' + rtrim(count(*)),
cast(SUM(case when Opened = blabla then 1 else 0 end) as float) / COUNT(*)
from #events
cross join (select distinct opened as blabla from #events) p
group by blabla

drop table #events
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
select sum
       ( case
         when -- open expression
         then 1
         else 0
         end
       )
       / count(*)
       percentage_open
 from  table
 group
 by    status
```